# PHP Kohana parse simple XML

Tags: php, xml

Having some problem parsing some XML in an application I am building. The format is as follows

```
<taskResponse statusCode="200">
    <session-states>
        <min-state>dfgdgdgd</min-state>
        <max-state>dgdfgd</max-state>
        <session-info>dgffdgd</session-info>
        <project-id>B19DEDCC11D4E0EFC000EB9495D0F44F</project-id>
    </session-states>
</taskResponse>
```

Attempting to use the following code to parse out the session-state value

```
public function parse_session_state($xml){
    echo $xml;
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
    echo $xml->session-states[0]->min-state;
    die();
}
```

but I get an error message

> ErrorException [ Parse Error ]: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: You should not put kohana tag and in title as this is clearly pure php question and might be misleading for people using search on portal.

Comment: Sure, the solution is pure php. Thought there might be something is Kohana that could be used as well.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
public function parse_session_state($xml){
  $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
  echo $xml->{'session-states'}->{'min-state'};

  die();
}
```